# Chef knife upload get ERROR: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory

Tags: chef-infra

I made some changes to a role on my local chef-repo and wanted to use knife upload roles to upload my changes to the chef-server but I get this error message

```
ERROR: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /home/danny/git/chef-repo/cookbooks/~/git/chef-repo
```

all knife upload commands get this error

I am able to use `bundle exec knife cookbook upload -a` successfully

any idea what going wrong

**MORE INFO**
*The Command I tried exactly was*
`knife upload /roles`     <---at the top of the my local chef-repo
&
`knife upload roles`      <--from the roles directory

*my knife.rb*

```
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                'admin'
client_key               '~/.chef/admin.pem'
validation_client_name   'chef-validator'
validation_key           '~/.chef/chef-validator.pem'
chef_server_url          'https://chef.example.org'
chef_server_ip           '10.32.2.53'
syntax_check_cache_path  '~/.chef/syntax_check_cache'
cookbook_path        [ '~/git/chef-repo/cookbooks', '~/git/chef-repo/site-cookbooks' ]

knife[:use_sudo] = true
knife[:ssh_user] = "emn"
knife[:use_sudo_password] = true
knife[:identity_file] = '~/.chef/emn.pem'
```

Comment: What are the contents of your `knife.rb`? Where are you running this from? What exact command did you run?

Comment: I add a more info part to answer your questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run `knife upload roles` from the root of your Chef repo. No slashes, no sub-directories.

Also, your roles much be JSON if you want to use `knife upload`. Otherwise you'll need to use `knife role from file`.

Comment: I am still getting the same error msg about no file or directory

Comment: Are your roles ruby or json?

Comment: `knife upload` does not support Ruby files

Comment: Really! if that is the case what command would I run to upload the roles I modified to the chef-server

Comment: oh so knife role from file (filename)